# why not instantiate class in php ? cannot declare clas

Tags: php, sql, forms, post, dto

i want save dto user in mysql bd, but to the create UserDto in php file (my controler) show this fatal error:

> Cannot declare class UserDto, because the name is already in use in C:\wamp\www\System_1\Dto\UserDto.php on line 9

my dto user class:

```
class UserDto { //line 9

private $id;
private $name;
private $age;

function __construct() {

}

   //getter and setters
}
```

my php file:

```
include_once '../../Dto/UserDto.php';  //here its fail
//also try
//include 'C:\wamp\www\System_1\Dto\UserDto.php';  
// but not work

$user = new UserDto();
$user->setId($_POST["txtId"]);
$user->setName($_POST["txtName"]);
$user->setAge($_POST["txtAge"]);
```

Comment: As given by the error message, The given class already exists among other classes. Try to rename your class to something else (e.g AnotherUserDto) and try again (e.g new AnotherUserDto())

Answer (score 1):

You are attempting to create a class that already exists. The class named UserDto already exists in UserDto.php. For that reason, it cannot declare it again. You can rename that class to something other than UserDto or use namespace.

Answer (score -1):

You must check the path of the file is correct or not.

check if include_once '../../Dto/UserDto.php'; exists or not on this path.

You are getting error as the path may be incorrect.